# How do I pass properties to stateless/functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my core `index.js` I am rendering a component like this:

```
<TestBundle lang={lang} />
```

I want to pick up the `lang` property inside that component.

Why is the variable undefined when I render it in `<TestBundle />`?

```
const TestBundle = (lang) => (
  <section className='relative-container'>
    <div className='row'>
        {lang}
    </div>
  </section>
)

export default TestBundle
```

==========================================================

---

so a modification suggested here

```
const TestBundle = (props) => {
  const lang = props.lang
  // ...
```

//different example

```
const TestBundle = (props) => {
    const lang = props.lang

      <section className='relative-container'>
        <div className='row'>
            {lang}
        </div>
      </section>
}

export default TestBundle
```

-- but this comes up with the error

```
./src/components/Services/TestBundle.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/wamp/www/project/react/src/components/Services/TestBundle.js: Unexpected token (5:2)

  3 | 
  4 | const TestBundle= (props) => {
> 5 |   const lang = props.lang
    |   ^
  6 |   
  7 |   <section className='relative-container'>
  8 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to destructure lang when you pass it to TestBundle, like this:

```
const TestBundle = ({lang}) => (
```

You can also validate your props, outside of your component (below it) like so:

```
TestBundle.propTypes = {
  lang: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: this works -- but comes up with the error - "4:20 error 'lang' is missing in props validation react/prop-types"

Comment: Did you add it to your proptypes?

Comment: Isn't this just a linter issue? The code should still work right?

Comment: Your solution worked @DouglasTylerGordon -- when I tried to use the method with the props, change brackets etc.. I got bugs with the markup

Answer (score 5):

`lang` is a property. You can destructure:

```
const TestBundle = ({ lang }) => (
```

Or do it manually:

```
const TestBundle = (props) => {
  const lang = props.lang
  // ...
```

Basic stateless component stuff; covered in all the docs: the parameter passed to a stateless/functional component is the component properties.